# SMS UDP application

Tags: java, windows, sockets, udp, sms

I'm devolping an SMS application that uses UDP protocol . My application need to do the following , client send to another client a message doesn't exceed 160 and he/she know the other client IP address . It will send through a server which will save it in case client is offline .

I started working on it but then I stopped ! I was having problem with these things .

How can multiple clients sends to server ? I searched about and I read about something called mutithreading , can anyone explain or give me example for it ?

also , I couldn't imagin the process of taking messages from clients and then saving it . I mean how the server know which message belong to which client ?

this is the code which I'm working on it

**server :**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 

class Server { 
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{ 

  DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876); 

  byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024]; 
  byte[] sendData  = new byte[1024]; 

  while(true) 
    { 

      DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
         new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
       serverSocket.receive(receivePacket); 

      String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData()); 

      InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress(); 

      int port = receivePacket.getPort(); 

                  String senderSentence = "From "+IPAddress+" Msg "+sentence; 

      sendData = senderSentence.getBytes(); 

      DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
         new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 
                           port); 

      serverSocket.send(sendPacket); 
    } } }
```

**client :**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{ 
String sentence;
  BufferedReader inFromUser = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

  DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(); 



  byte[] sendData = new byte[1024]; 
  byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024]; 
  do {
  System.out.println("Enter a msg , NOTE: don't exceed 160 charcter");
  sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
  }
  while(sentence.length() >= 160);
  System.out.println("Enter the adress of the other user");
  String ip=inFromUser.readLine();
  InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip); 
  sendData = sentence.getBytes();         
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
     new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876); 

  clientSocket.send(sendPacket); 

  DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
     new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 

  clientSocket.receive(receivePacket); 

  String modifiedSentence = 
      new String(receivePacket.getData()); 

  System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence); 
  clientSocket.close(); 
  } }
```

Thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to use UDP - but if this isn't some special requirement you might want to look at using a web server.

I quite like the [Play Framework for Java](http://www.playframework.com/), which is going to handle the threading for you. Every time you send a message to the server it is just like sending a request for a web page, so you can reply with JSON or XML or whatever you think is best.

This is going to be a lot easier than handling all the socket communication yourself - but as I say, maybe you have a special requirement.

Hope this helps!